# Cannot invoke call from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, closures, sdwebimage

I have read a couple similar questions, but none of them were working for me. Well, I am trying to show different images on a list and save those images in cache. I am getting error on iconView.sd call.

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var item: ItemRealm? {
    didSet {
        if item == nil {
            iconView.image = nil
            itemTitleLabel.text = "Test"
            itemDescLabel.text = "Some description"
        } else {
            // TODO: Implement item sets
            iconView.sd_setImage(with: NSURL(string: (item?.icon)!),
                                 placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), 
                                 completed: { (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!, cachetype: SDImageCacheType, imageURL: NSURL!) in

                                            })
            itemTitleLabel.text = item?.name
            itemDescLabel.text = item?.desc

        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var iconView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemDescLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    iconView.layer.cornerRadius = 4
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.item = nil
}

}
```

> Error : *TableViewCell.swift:22:26: Cannot invoke 'sd_setImageWithURL'
>   with an argument list of type '(NSURL?, placeholderImage: UIImage?,
>   completed: (UIImage!, NSError!, SDImageCacheType, NSURL!) -> ())*'

Icons from list(log):

```
 ; icon: Optional("http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/items/0/icon.png")
 ; icon: Optional("http://192.168.1.101:8080/api/items/1/icon.png")...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be because of the use of old NS-Types, which got replaced in Swift3 and getting mapped to the new Datatypes by Swift3 automatically now.

```
iconView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item!.icon),
         placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"),
                  options: .highPriority) { image, error, cacheType, imageURL in
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting error: Ambiguous use of 'sd_setImage'.

Comment: Just tried it and experienced the same, even when I specify the types correctly as in my edited answer. It only works for me when I add the `options:` argument.

Comment: Okey. Thanks a lot.Where add this options: argument If I may ask?

Comment: I edited my answer how i would write it and how i just checked it in xcode.

Comment: Yes, it's also working. Thanks for your input. You forgot completed: after calling options: highPriority

Comment: No I left it out on purpose. It's called trailing closure. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me. Remember to add options: argument like this.

```
iconView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: item!.icon), placeholderImage: 
      UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), options: SDWebImageOptions(), 
      completed: { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cachetype: SDImageCacheType,
     imageURL: URL?) in
            })
```